# Buffered Output Stream

Tags: java

I have notice a behavior for output stream class (buffered output stream) and I want to understand it to resolve my issue , that when I create an object to write text data in file it is OK but when try to write again with another object of same class it work fine but replace previous text with new one

```
class writeFile extneds BufferedOutputStream{
  public static void main(String arg[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{

    new writeFile(new FileOutputStream(file)).setComments("hello");
    new writeFile(new FileOutputStream(file)).setComments("Hi");

}

   public void setComments(String s) throws IOException
   {
       this.write(this.setBytes(s+"\r\n\n"));
    this.write(this.setBytes("-----------------------------------\r\n\n"));
   }
```

when execute it I find just Hi word and the first word is not there because it replaced with last one so why when I use another object to write some text it write from beginning and replace with before it and is there any solution because when I close the program and open it again it will be new declaration for object and this considered as new object

Comment: What is `setBytes()`? Why are you exending `BufferedOutputStream`?

Comment: `new FileOutputStream(file)` opens the file for writing and truncates the contents. Why does this surprise you?

Comment: setBytes is a method that take a string as parameter and convert it to byte array , I extends it to use protected buffer from class and take some feature of buffering before writing

Comment: Also, do not forget to close file streams properly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`FileOutputStream(String, boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream-java.io.File-boolean-) constructor, where the second parameter is to **append**. Easiest fix I see, change

```
new writeFile(new FileOutputStream(file)).setComments("Hi");
```

to

```
new writeFile(new FileOutputStream(file, true)).setComments("Hi");
```

Personally, I think, it would be better to use one `OutputStream` (and your `writeFile` is one possible such class). And you should always `close` your resources (you could use a [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)). Finally, Java naming conventions have classes start with a capital letter - `writeFile` *looks* like a method name.

```
try (writeFile fos = new writeFile(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
    fos.setComments("hello");
    fos.setComments("Hi");
}
```

Comment: And `close()` the file.